# sum column Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, max

Hello I have data in 3 tables, code below.

Sql Oracle

```
 select distinct 
 t2.coll_no,
 t1.account_number,
 t1.commitment_number,
 t3.APPRAISAL_AMT

 from table1 t1
 LEFT JOIN table2 t2
 ON T2.OBLIGATION_ACCOUNT_NUMBER = T1.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
 AND T2.OBLIGATION_NUMBER = T1.COMMITMENT_NUMBER
 LEFT jOIN table3 t3
 ON t3.COLL_NO = t3.cOLL_NO
```

Each coll_no has a different afs_appraisal amount.

Instead of 5 rows with the only difference being the appraisal amount, I want one row with the sum of the 5 appraisal amounts.

Comment: Sample data and desired results would really help.

Comment: Figured it out Sorry guys needed to remove the coll_no column 

select distinct 

c1.account_number,
c1.commitment_number,
sum(C3.AFS_APPRAISAL_AMT)
from commitment c1

LEFT JOIN Collateral_Obligation C2
  ON C2.OBLIGATION_ACCOUNT_NUMBER = C1.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
  AND C2.OBLIGATION_NUMBER = C1.COMMITMENT_NUMBER
LEFT jOIN COLLATERAL C3
ON C2.COLL_NO = C3.cOLL_NO

where c1.account_number = 266610 and c1.commitment_number =1 

group by c1.account_number, c1.commitment_number

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your syntax/logic is correct, you need a sum on the t3.APPRAISAL_AMT and GROUP BY some other attribute which below I assumed t2.coll_no.

```
select distinct 
   t2.coll_no,
   t1.account_number,
   t1.commitment_number,
   SUM(t3.APPRAISAL_AMT)

 from table1 t1
 LEFT JOIN table2 t2
   ON T2.OBLIGATION_ACCOUNT_NUMBER = T1.ACCOUNT_NUMBER
   AND T2.OBLIGATION_NUMBER = T1.COMMITMENT_NUMBER
 LEFT jOIN table3 t3
   ON t3.COLL_NO = t3.cOLL_NO
 GROUP BY t2.coll_no
```

Comment: Syntax error: you have columns in the select-list which are not part of the `GROUP BY` (only MySQL and, in certain situations, PostgreSQL, allow doing so, but it's often suspect).  If they did match, `DISTINCT` would be useless (and probably optimized out), since that would happen during the grouping.

Comment: I tried to group it by the commitment number

but when group using oracle it gives me an error saying 


ORA-00979: not a GROUP BY expression
00979. 00000 -  "not a GROUP BY expression"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 16

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want conditional aggregation:

```
select sum(case when t2.coll_no = <val1> then t3.appraisal_amt end) as appraisal_1,
       sum(case when t2.coll_no = <val2> then t3.appraisal_amt end) as appraisal_2,
       sum(case when t2.coll_no = <val3> then t3.appraisal_amt end) as appraisal_3,
       sum(case when t2.coll_no = <val4> then t3.appraisal_amt end) as appraisal_4,
       sum(case when t2.coll_no = <val5> then t3.appraisal_amt end) as appraisal_5
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on T2.OBLIGATION_ACCOUNT_NUMBER = T1.ACCOUNT_NUMBER and
        T2.OBLIGATION_NUMBER = T1.COMMITMENT_NUMBER left join
     table3 t3
     on t3.COLL_NO = t3.cOLL_NO;
```